# Insert id (auto increment) into other table in same moment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables:

client table:

```
--------------------------------------
id_client | name_client | email_client
--------------------------------------
```

skill table:

```
--------------------------------------
id_skill  | client      | number
--------------------------------------
```

I use CodeIgniter, I have one controller that add new client. I have a form that contains input form, but in `client table`, `id_client` is `auto increment`, I want to insert `id_client` value into `client` column in `skill table` at the same moment (controller).  So I have two model `$this->m_admin->save_client($clientdata);` and `$this->m_admin->save_skill($skilldata);`

Can you help me, how to insert auto increment id into other table at the same moment?

Comment: How do you mean in same moment? 
Maybe you should make one more column in each table and call it crated_at. Actually common use is to have two tables called created_at and updated_at (second one is for later edit). So you need to use insert data into first column. After successful insert you would grab last insert id and use it for second query that would give you created_at value. Than you should insert all collected data into second table. Smart move is to use roll back of [transactions](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html).

Comment: I mean in the same controller, so one execution for two queries. but I have found the answer, it's SOLVED. Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED, I use `$this->db->insert_id()` to get last ID in auto increment. First run the main queries and then second queries ( the queries that need ID of first queries). For more info in Codeigniter user guide https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

Now I See You Found :)